# Ways to inject functionality (similar to dynamic proxy but less intrusive)

Tags: java, proxy, code-injection

What possibilities do I have to add functionality to methods (annotated) without bothering the developer by using dynamic proxies?

Classical example:

```
public int sum(int x, int y){
   StaticInstance.doThisBefore(x,y); // ccc
   int result = x+y;  // business functionality
   StaticInstance.doThisAfter(result); // ccc
   return result;
}
```

So exactly what a dynamic proxy can do. The problem with dynamic proxy is, it's way to intrusive.

- Annotation processor let's you only create new classes but not modifying existing ones (am I correct?)
- Modifying byte code?
- Codeweaver?
- Agent cannot be used.

The developer might be using Spring framework, Java EE or whatever framework he likes so it's very important that the style & way the developer codes is not affected.

**So it's very important that the option should be unintrusive.**

Comment: Do you want to modify source or byte code?

Comment: Take a look to AspectJ?

Comment: @ArcticLord both ways are possible - whatever works best? Any idea?

Comment: @DavidL I've already checked out AspectJ but it's even more intrusive, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an abstract class to the programmers, with a method that calls the actual business method to be implemented from subclasses.
The method that would invoke the full functionality should be supported by an interface:

```
public interface Service {
    int getResult(int x, int y);
}
```

And the abstract class implements the interface, but leaves the actual business logic method to be implemented by subclasses:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass implements Service {
    public int getResult(int x, int y) {
        StaticInstance.doThisBefore(x,y); // ccc
        int result = process(x, y);
        StaticInstance.doThisAfter(result); // ccc
    }

    // this is the actual business logic to be implemented by subclasses
    public abstract int process(int x, int y);
}
```

And the subclass would implement the actual business logic like:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {
    public int process(int x, int y) {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

So, the developer has to remember only to subclass `AbstractClass` but his code deals only with the actual business logic.

Finally, the call to this service from your code would be:

```
Service myService = new MyClass();
System.out.println(myService.getResult(5, 6));
```

Comment: @Reymanx Is this answer good for you? Do you want to accept it?